# Kdenlive Effect Section is White

Tags: effects, kdenlive, bug

Kdenlive is displaying a white window in the effect section instead of the expected list of effects, as seen in the accompanying image. I encountered this issue on both Fedora 36 and Fedora 37, using Kdenlive version 22.12.2.

I would greatly appreciate any help or suggestions in resolving this issue. If there is any additional information I can provide to help diagnose the problem, please let me know.

[image: bug illustration]

Answer (score 0):

don't know if still actual, ran into the exact same problem and solved it with
`apt-get install -y qml-module-org-kde-kcm`